# how to find the most letter(s) with the same frequency

Tags: for-loop, nested, structure

I just started using java, I'm trying to create a nested for-loop (without using arrays) that gives me how many letters (from alphabet) have a frequency of zero in a string. So if my string is "test", then it should display "23 letters" as an answer because only 3 out of 26 letters are in the string. However, my program is missing information. I'm trying to make sure my program can target the specific frequency I'm looking for ie. 0.

Here is my program so far:

```
public class FindMaxandMinofString {

public static void main(String[] args) {         

char charToLookFor;
String s = "test";
int count = 0;

for (charToLookFor = 'a'; charToLookFor = 'z' ;charToLookFor++)
{
    for(int l = 0; l < s.length(); l++) {
        if(s.charAt(l) == charToLookFor)
        count++;
}
System.out.print(count);
```

}

Comment: Does the target frequency need to be variable or will it always be 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of counting of a count of 0, start from a count of 26 and subtract from it whenever you find a new letter. It is import to `break` from the loop when you find one otherwise you may count each letter more than once.

```
public class FindMaxandMinofString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {         

        char charToLookFor;
        String s = "test";
        int count = 26;

        for (charToLookFor = 'a'; charToLookFor <= 'z' ;charToLookFor++)
        {
            for(int l = 0; l < s.length(); l++)
            {
                if(s.charAt(l) == charToLookFor)
                {
                    count--;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print(count + " letters");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this task by using a hash set - when you find a character, add it to the hash set. Your answer will be 26 minus the size of the final hash set after you're done iterating through the entire string.